# gcc is not Creating an Output File

Tags: powershell, gcc, windows-7

The following command (via PowerShell in Windows 7)

```
PS C:\Users\gvkv\projects\stats> C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe .\lex.yy.c -o gmstats.exe -v output
```

gives the following output

```
gcc.exe: error: output: No such file or directory
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

and I have no idea why.  In particular, I don't understand the error at the top of the output.  If I invoke `gcc` without the -v option:

```
PS C:\Users\gvkv\projects\stats> C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe .\lex.yy.c -o gmstats.exe
```

I get:

```
PS C:\Users\gvkv\projects\stats>
```

Nominal success! This would be great if I also had gmstats.exe in my directory.  Just for fun I've also tried running PowerShell as an administrator and I've also invoked `gcc` with an absolute path:

```
PS ...>C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
```

just to make sure.  I last used `gcc` to compile something (via `make`) and it worked fine.

I also considered that there was a linker (`ld.exe`) problem but there's no file to link and the search directories are fine.

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, but for these sorts of problems it is often helpful to use Process Monitor from Sysinternals. That might give you a clue about what is going on. I would start with a filter of "path contains 'gmstats.exe'", or "process contains 'gcc'".

Comment: @gvkv Have you tried with `.\output`?

Comment: I did try that but it only worked without the `-v ...` option or anything trailing `-o ...`.  Writing a I'm thinking it's a PowerShell issue since everything works fine if I compile via a `make` file.